# Join in mongodb using nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My patient model is like this:

```
PatientModel=new Schema({
   "PatientID":{type:String},
   "PatientGender":{type:String},
   "PatientDateOfBirth":{type:Date},
   "PatientRace":{type:String},
   "PatientMaritalStatus":{type:String},
   "PatientLanguage":{type:String},
   "PatientPopulationPercentageBelowPoverty":{type:Number},
   "FirstName":{type:String},
   "LastName":{type:String},
   "City":{type:String}
});
```

and disease model

```
DiseaseModel=new Schema({
   "PatientID":{type:String},
   "AdmissionID":{type:Number},
   "PrimaryDiagnosisCode":{type:String},
   "Disease":{type:String}
});
```

I want to get the count of patients having a particular **"Diseases"**(which is in DiseaseModel) group by **"City"**  (which is in PatientModel) arranged in descending order and limited upto 10 cities. How I can write the query in nodejs ?

Sample data for disease:

```
{
"PatientID": "170EF37F-1098-462C-838F-C56C5455CB98",
"AdmissionID": 3,
"PrimaryDiagnosisCode": "C00.1",
"PrimaryDiagnosisDescription": "Malignant neoplasm of external lower lip"
 }
```

Sample data for patient:

```
{
"PatientID": "170EF37F-1098-462C-838F-C56C5455CB98",
"PatientGender": "Male",
"PatientDateOfBirth": "1951-09-26 08:48:36.700",
"PatientRace": "White",
"PatientMaritalStatus": "Married",
"PatientLanguage": "English",
"PatientPopulationPercentageBelowPoverty": 14.15,
"FirstName": "BENJAMIN",
"LastName": "YIN",
"City": "Gokak",
}
```

Comment: Arranged in Descending Order by What? Disease Name?

Comment: @SiddharthAjmera Descending order of the count of the patients.

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data for your `Patient` and `Disease ` collection?

Comment: I added sample data in question. @SiddharthAjmera

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB doesn't support joins. So with this model, I don't think it can be done. What you can do though is, add a `diseases` field in your `PatientModel` which would be an array of strings. Something like this:

```
PatientModel=new Schema({
    "PatientID":{type:String},
    "PatientGender":{type:String},
    "PatientDateOfBirth":{type:Date},
    "PatientRace":{type:String},
    "PatientMaritalStatus":{type:String},
    "PatientLanguage":{type:String},
    "PatientPopulationPercentageBelowPoverty":{type:Number},
    "FirstName":{type:String},
    "LastName":{type:String},
    "City":{type:String},
    "Diseases": { type: [String] }
});
```

Then you can simply use this aggregation query. This is for the Mongo Shell. But a Mongoose Equivalent of this will work.

```
db.patients.aggregate([
    { $match: { Diseases: your_specified_disease } },
    { $group: {
                  _id: { city: "$City" },
                  patients_count: { $sum : 1 }
              } },
    { $sort: { patients_count: -1 } },
    { $limit: 10 }
]);
```

I just tested it. It's working.

**EDIT:**
If you're not willing to change your schema, then as Neil suggested, you can use `$lookup`. Here is what your query should look like in that case:

```
db.diseases.aggregate([
    { $match: { Disease: your_specified_disease } },
    { $lookup:  {
                    from: "patients",
                    localField: "PatientID",
                    foreignField: "PatientID",
                    as: "Patient"
            }
    },
    { $group: {
                  _id: { city: "$Patient.City" },
                  patients_count: { $sum : 1 }
              } },
    { $sort: { patients_count: -1 } },
    { $limit: 10 }
])
```

I haven't tested this one as I didn't have all the data you have. But please test this and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Lets say that I first give the query to the disease collection and get all the patients with Disease:"A" and with this patients data can I query the Patient collection ? That means I will query the DB 2 times...

Comment: Yes you can. Then you'll have to query with `$in` for `PatientID`. It's going to make your query logic more complex. This was a simple suggestion.

Comment: Please give me some time. I'll get back to this.

Comment: If I use $in then how will the query will look like ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108479/discussion-between-shubham-and-siddharth-ajmera).